# Answer File PowerShell Script To Run On First Boot Of a Fresh Install

Tags: powershell

I added this FirstLogonCommand to my answer file.

`powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoExit -file D:\DisableGuard.ps1 -Disable`

I don't want it to exit to see the output so I added -NoExit
The -Disable switch is the correct switch for the script.

Am I formatting it correctly to run with that switch in an answer file?
It runs correctly if I run it direct from an admin command prompt.

Comment: You may be able to test it from a VM - have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it, it works fine. But actually by installing Windows.  I can't really test it in a VM because the file path won't find the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `help about_PowerShell.exe` in PS it will show you the command, syntax and formatting.

It looks like you have the correct syntax